# Jenkins does not trigger builds when commits are force pushed into repo

Tags: git, jenkins

I have Jenkins + Stash integration. I have set up Stash Webhook to Jenkins to enable builds to be automated upon push to Stash. And i find that when i force push a commit into Stash, Jenkins does not build it. If its a normal push, then Jenkins triggers the build. Anybody has faced this problem?

Just another silly question in conjunction to this - Does Jenkins job receive Stash notifications when I am configuring the job at the same time as the notification is fired by Stash?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Projects / Repository / Settings / Hooks` and check that you haven't enabled `Reject Force Push`.
- BTW editing Job does not interfere with Jenkins being notified.

Comment: I have checked the settings and found that Reject Force Push is disabled. Any other checks i need to do? Is there a place where I can see the Commit notifications fired by Stash to Jenkins(some sort of log)?

Comment: After `git-push` have you tried triggering Jenkins remotely by sending a trigger signal manually with `curl`, ie. `curl http://jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@git-server//project.git` ? Also you should be able to check `Git Polling Log` from left-side project's menu. What does it show?

Comment: Nope i have not tried curl.
I have set up polling but it is set up only for name-sake and its polling frequency is once a year. As of now it is just used as a pre-requisite for enabling the webhook functionality to work fine. The log does not say anything. The current log is the one that was generated a few days back when i was testing it with polling. 
As of now, what i see on Stash is just the latest commit (force pushed one). The commit that was made just before that has dissappeared(could be that it is now removed by garbage collection). Does this explain this behaviour?

Comment: Also, i have tried triggering manually using the Build option in Jenkins and then it triggers the build fine. I guess that is similar to what the curl does.

Comment: `curl` acts the same way you trigger build from Stash, and in my private opinion is different from manual starting a build. If `curl` works that could mean that problem is on Stash side.